# How can I use Swift Package Manager (SPM) and cocoapods together in one project?

Tags: cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have an existing project which uses Cocoapods, but I would like to switch to SPM; unfortunately I still have dependencies which aren't available in SPM.

Now I would like to move as many dependencies as possible over to SPM and keep the others in Cocoapods as long as necessary - is this possible? Having both, Cocoapods and SPM?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I’m facing the same issue

Answer (score 33):

I just tried CocoaPods with SPM on my iOS project and it works fine.
I'm adding Firebase and other Google libs using CocoaPods and the rest using Swift Package Manager.

When adding SPM dependency, put checkmark on your project(s) and not on the Pods project.

Xcode 11.5,
CocoaPods 1.9.3.

Comment: is there a version you could upload somewhere public? Would be interested in how you did it...

Comment: What if one of your private packages depends on a cocoapod library? do you have a way to link against that?

Comment: You should provide and answer and not just it's working...

Comment: @Paul, I added CocoaPods using `pod install` and then added SPM dependencies using File → Swift Packages → Add Package Dependency and ticking my project (and not Pods project)

Comment: @PavelAlexeev Thanks did it already though. Thanks for the response really appreciate. I just simply added a Package using SPM within the same project where I had used CocoaPods/other packages and it worked no issues.

Answer (score 3):

As of XCode 14.2 and CocoaPods 1.13, you can definitely still use Swift Package Manager alongside Cocoapods, which is super helpful for migrating dependencies over slowly.

The process has changed just a bit since 2020, so here's the updated version

1. Go to `File`, then at the top of the list click `Add Packages`
2. A window should open listing Apple packages you can add as dependencies. The top right corner has a search bar where you can paste the Github package URL of the dependency you need. Doing so will fetch that Package from Github, and allow you to setup the dependency before adding.
3. Once the dependency you needed has been fetched, input the version you want, and how much you would like XCode to update it (since it'll update the package automatically for you). Typically `Up to Next Major Version` is fine since it'll take a package where you input 1.1 for the version all the way up to 1.99 without ever making the jump to 2.0 where breaking changes might occur.
4. The MOST IMPORTANT PART is to be sure before you add the package, you use the `Add to Project` dropdown to select your specific project's name, NOT the Pods project that Cocoapods will have made for you when using it.
5. Once you're sure you have the right settings, hit `Add Package` and you should be all set.

Besides these steps, it's worth noting that you should commit the `swiftpm` folder that will be built and more specifically that the `Package.resolved` file should be included in your `source control`/`git`.

Also if your project fails to build correctly after adding the SPM dependency, then go to `Project` and click `Clean Build Folder`. Afterward, try rebuilding your App. If you encounter any other build issues, repeat this process as you actually add in `import TheNewDependencyName` in your project or tests. You can also try this process, closing and reopening XCode after the cleaning finishes, which occasionally seems to help the often finicky XCode.

As always if using Cocoapods, you'll have to continue opening the project with the `xcworkspace` file created in the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

After trying it out I found you can actually have a SPM + Cocoapods to play nice. You install your SPM library on the .xcodeproj while you develop on the .xcworkspace. It all works (at least so far for me lol).

If you are using CI, or you launch manually from xcodebuild command some tweaks with the `-clonedSourcePackagesDirPath` flag

Answer (score 0):

I have had used swift package manager at the beginning and added 4 packages in my project. When I had to integrate admob sdk. I added cocoapod to my project.
but after open the .xcworkspace file. the packages status are display as Missing. I have to add them from SPM one by one. after all 4 packages were added again. the project can be built and executed again.

Answer (score -8):

Considering all the pros and cons, I found it suitable to use CocoaPods as SPM is still at a very nascent stage and not all libraries support it.
Please go through the blog written by Darshan Patel by https://blog.kiprosh.com/preferable-dependency-manager-swift-package-manager-spm-or-cocoapods/ for more details.

Comment: The question is not about advantages and disadvantages of SPM.